# using dao layer in a nosql ( mongo db) app

Tags: mongodb, design-patterns

So far, I've not been able to use an example app that uses the dao layer when using a nosql to access the database(e.g. mongo db). Is it suitable/good practise to use this design pattern when using nosql databases?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code that you tried